Font issue with Excel PostScript and TrueType
I have a big issue with excel\Windows font (I do not know from where it come from). This problem persist since 3 weeks. Honestly I try here but I discsussed with my IT  acouple of time without success. I have a default font in the format True Type Outlines and I would like to have as default the PostScript Outlines. The space between the lines are bigger with the TrueType so it offset all the format on my Excel. I took the PostScript from a colleague who does not have the issue. I cannot replace the font in the folder FONT, the TrueType stay as default, I cannot cancel the TrueType, because I do not have the right and my IT does not want to delete it. Please help me.
Keep PostScript Outlines.
